# Python classmethod outside the class

Tags: python, class-method

I have to use some Python library which contains file with various utilities: classes and methods. One of these methods is defined in the following way (I cannot put whole code):

```
@classmethod
def do_something(cls, args=None, **kwargs):
```

but this declaration is outside any class. How can I get access to this method? Calling by `do_something(myClass)` gives an error: `TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable`. What is the purpose of creating classmethods outside classes?

Comment: What do you mean *outside any class*? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: This method is at the top-level of nesting, without any indentation.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a self-defined decorator called 'classmethod' which happend to overwrite this key name.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696455

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decorator produces a `classmethod` object. Such objects are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) (just like `staticmethod`, `property` and function objects).

Perhaps the code is re-using that object as such a descriptor. You can add it to a class at a later time:

```
ClassObject.attribute_name = do_something
```

or you can explicitly call the [`descriptor.__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__).

By storing it as a global it is easier to retrieve; if you put it on a class you'd have to reach into the class `__dict__` attribute to retrieve the `classmethod` descriptor without invoking it:

```
ClassObject.__dict__['do_something']
```

as straight attribute access would cause Python to call the `descriptor.__get_` method for you, returning a bound method:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def bar(cls):
...         print 'called bar on {}'.format(cls.__name__)
... 
>>> Foo.bar
<bound method type.bar of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
>>> Foo.bar()
called bar on Foo
>>> Foo.__dict__['bar']
<classmethod object at 0x1076b20c0>
>>> Foo.__dict__['bar'].__get__(None, Foo)
<bound method type.bar of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
>>> Foo.__dict__['bar'].__get__(None, Foo)()
called bar on Foo
```