# python classmethods are not callable from class.__dict__

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, class-method

I am learning the concept of `classmethods` in python.

```
class A():
    n=0
    # object method
    def func_o(self):
        self.n += 1
        print self.n

    # well, class method
    @classmethod
    def func_c(cls):
        cls.n += 1
        print cls.n
```

when checking the `callable()` attributes of the class, I came across with this peculiar output:

```
>>> [(k, callable(v)) for k,v in A.__dict__.items()]
[('__module__', False), ('__doc__', False), ('func_o', True), ('func_c', False), ('n', False)]
```

`('func_o', True)` even though the class `__dict__` was inspected, similarly `('func_c', False)` for some reason.

Can someone explain?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284275

Answer (score 9):

A `classmethod` object is not a function object, no. It is not meant to be callable.

`classmethod` objects are *descriptors*; descriptors facilitate the binding of an object to a specific instance or class. Functions and properties are also descriptors; binding produces methods, or the property value, respectively. See the [Python Descriptor How To](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). If you were to access a `classmethod` descriptor on the class, then this triggers a `classmethod.__get__(None, cls)` call that produces a bound method (which, when called, invokes the original function with the class object passed in as the first argument).

When you access all class attributes through the `__dict__` attribute, you are bypassing the descriptor protocol, so you get the raw descriptor objects themselves.

Either access the object on the class (and thus trigger the `descriptor.__get__(None, cls)` call that binds class methods to the class object), manually bind, or test explicitly for `classmethod` objects:

```
>>> A.__dict__['func_c']
<classmethod object at 0x1018e6cc8>
>>> A.__dict__['func_c'].__get__(None, A)  # explicitly bind to a class
<bound method classobj.func_c of <class __main__.A at 0x101c52328>>
>>> callable(A.__dict__['func_c'].__get__(None, A))
True
>>> A.func_c    # trigger the protocol and bind to a class
<bound method classobj.func_c of <class __main__.A at 0x101c52328>>
```

You can also access the original function that the `classmethod` object wraps, using the `__func__` attribute:

```
>>> A.__dict__['func_c'].__func__
<function func_c at 0x101c59668>
```

which is, of course, itself callable too.

Note that this all applies to `staticmethod` objects too; a `staticmethod` object, when bound, just returns the original function.