# Pytest no tests ran

Tags: python, bash, pytest

From Linux mint bash I type

```
$ pytest tests/parser_test.py 
=============================== test session starts py ================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/rat/Projects/ex48, inifile:
collected 0 items                                                                   

=========================== no tests ran in 0.00 seconds ===========================
```

and yet it says there are "no test ran".  I did each function test in stages and it worked for a while but I noticed that with each additional function pytest was picking up less test(s).  I have a funny feeling it is with my testing code, however I am not sure what it is that I am doing wrong or even what to search for it.  I tried changing some of the variables from word_list_one to wl_one to see if that was the problem with no success. I also check stack over similar questions but could not find the answer.  I must admit this is my first language that I have learnt so I'm very new to this whole testing thing. Here is my Project tree

    `.
    ├── ex48
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── lexicon.py
    │   ├── parser.py
    │   └── parser.pyc
    ├── README.md
    ├── setup.py
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── lexicon_tests.py
        ├── parser_test.py
        └── __pycache__
            ├── parser_test.cpython-27-PYTEST.pyc
            └── parser_tests.cpython-27-PYTEST.pyc`

```
import pytest
from ex48 import parser
from ex48.parser import Sentence

# test parse_sentence
@pytest.fixture()
def test_sentence():
    sentence = Sentence.parse_sentence([("noun","player"),("verb", "go"),("noun", "bear")])
    return sentence


def test_peek():
    result = test_sentence()
    assert Sentence.peek(result) != None
```

After removing @classmethod, correct answer from hansaplast, I needed to change the test_sentence and added test_sentence(self) to ```[as1 per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473184/unbound-method-f-must-be-called-with-fibo-instance-as-first-argument-got-cla):

```
@pytest.fixture()
def test_sentence(self):
    sentence = Sentence()
    return sentence.parse_sentence([("noun","player"),("verb", "go"),("noun", "bear")])
```

However now I have an issue with the pytest fixture

```
$ pytest tests/parser_test.py 
============================== ERRORS ====================================
___________________ ERROR at setup of test_peek __________________________
file /home/rat/Projects/ex48/tests/parser_test.py, line 13
    def test_peek(test_sentence):
file /home/rat/Projects/ex48/tests/parser_test.py, line 7
    @pytest.fixture()
    def test_sentence(self):
E       fixture 'self' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capsys, doctest_namespace,
        monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, 
        test_sentence, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

So I typed $ pytest --fixtures tests/parser_test.py and received a lot of information that doesn't make sense to me and this:

```
------------- fixtures defined from tests.parser_test -------------------
test_sentence
tests/parser_test.py:8: no docstring available
```

Might be easier to delete and start over without @pytest.fixtures =^/

Comment: Don't post screenshots, especially of text commands.

Comment: Where is the actual output? I bet there's interesting messages you aren't bothering to mention.

Comment: Please explain the `@classmethod` decorator outside of a class.

Comment: As for the @classmethod.  The tests are calling fuctions from within parser.py.  https://github.com/tcratius/ex48.git

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer: Remove the `@classmethod` annotation and your test will be called.

Longer answer: Having `@classmethod` outside a class is a somehow esoteric thing, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284275/python-classmethod-outside-the-class) explains that it just produces a descriptor which can later be bound to a class using `MyClass.attribute_name = test_peek`. That means that pytest will see `test_peek` not as a function but as an object and thus will not call it. Looking through your `ex48` code on github you're not assigning this object to any class, so you probably misunderstood the meaning of `@classmethod` and should just remove this annotation.

> After removing @classmethod, correct answer from hansaplast, I needed to change the test_sentence and added test_sentence(self)

I quickly looked up [your code on github](https://github.com/tcratius/ex48), there are several things wrong with your code

- why do you need the `@pytest.fixture()` at all? You are just adding the annotations but not using it then
- you need to look up to correctly work with classes. your class `Sentence` in only have functions (that is: none of them uses `self` as argument), also, in `parser_tests.py` you have functions which have self as first parameter, even they are not in a class. Functions outside classes don't take `self`, functions (=methods) within classes take `self` as first parameter.

Comment: OK, makes sense.  Unfortunately this causes another issue which was initially solve by using @classmethod.  Sigh

Comment: can you explain the issue you run into when you remove `@classmethod`?

Comment: Wasn't sure if I was allowed to do this on stakeoverflow, must confess I try not to post on here.  NameError: global name 'parse_object' is not defined <--- parse_object is a function in the parser.py file.

Comment: @ConradThiele I added a section in my answer. Please read up some documentation about classes in python, then you need to rework your code

Comment: Cheers, I have been struggling with classes for a good six months.  Not the brightest tool in the shed.  I look more into to classes. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: People take it for granted being smart.  Oh well, will keep trying.

Comment: no worries, I also started Python a while back. It takes time. But learning about python basics you better read up some basic documentation first, I cannot really transfer this knowledge over stackoverflow answers

Comment: if you look at lexicon.py I think I achieved what you are referring to and yes getting the basics right is definitely important